# How to combine WHERE clauses in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to have this kind of query in Eloquent:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 AND (type = 2 OR type = 3 OR type = 4)
```

I've been unable to find an easy way of doing this in Eloquent. If I use

```
Table::where('status', 1)->orWhere('type', 2)->orWhere('type', 3)...
```

This this translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 OR type = 2 OR type = 3 OR type = 4
```

Which is not what I need. Creating a query scope for 'status = 1' also gets me the same results. How can I run this query in Eloquent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To group where clauses like that, you need to pass a closure to the `where()` method, and add your grouped conditions inside the closure. So, your code would look something like:

```
Table::where('status', 1)->where(function ($q) {
    return $q->where('type', 2)->orWhere('type', 3)->orWhere('type', 4);
});
```

This will generate the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE status = 1 AND (type = 2 OR type = 3 OR type = 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent allows [nested parameter groupings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) passing a Closure as the  argument of `where`, `orWhere`, or the undocumented but more expressive `whereNested`:

```
Table::where('status', 1)
    ->whereNested(function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 2)
              ->orWhere('type', 3)
              ->orWhere('type', 4);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may run a raw query and type exactly what you want:
See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

you can try `parameter grouping` in `where` to achieve what you want.

```
Table::where('status', 1)->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 2)
                  ->orWhere('type', 3)
                  ->orWhere('type',4);})
```

For more info check [laravel Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try THis:

```
Table::where(function($query){
        $query->where('status', 1)
            ->orWhere('type', 2)
            ->orWhere('type', 3);
});
```

Comment: This is similar to the query without passing function to where close. `Table::where('status', 1)->orWhere('type', 2)->orWhere('type', 3)`. The only way to produce a query with some where clause grouped in parentheses is when you have at least one `where` or `orWhere` clause which are at the some level with the `where` or `orWhere` clause to which you pass a function which receive the query builder