# unable to search name with short name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, full-text-search

we have a table where names are like

`Hyper Text Markup Language`

`Cascading Style Sheets`

`Active Server Pages`

`Java Server Pages`

now we want to search them with short name also like

`html`

`css`

`asp`

`jsp`

so we created a column for short name, but our laravel query is not working properly, can you help what is the issue with it?

```
$names = Language::where('short_name','like','%' . $name . '%')
        ->orWhere('name','like','%' . $name . '%')
        ->where('public','=',1)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Change this `->get();` to `->toSql();` and share value of `echo $names` ?

Comment: I think the problem might be in the logic. It should be `(A or B) and C`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949380/how-to-combine-where-clauses-in-eloquent .

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408201/query-clause-with-two-wherein](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408201/query-clause-with-two-wherein) Please visit this link this will hep you a lot.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$names = Language::where(function( $query){
              $query->where('short_name','like','%' . $name . '%')
                    ->orWhere('name','like','%' . $name . '%');
          })->where('public','=',1)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->get();
```