# Query clause with two whereIn

Tags: laravel

I try to run this query , all is good till :

> ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])

this second whereIn seems to not work , it's display me only statut_licence_id = 1 and not also 4 , someone now how to resolve the problem ?

```
        $licencies = Licencies::whereIn('structure_id', $structures->pluck('id'))->whereIn('type_licence_id', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->where('lb_assurance_etat' ,'=' , 'Assurée')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

problem solved with :

```
$licencies = Licencies::whereIn('structure_id', $structures->pluck('id'))->whereIn('type_licence_id', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']) ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1'); })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Try printing raw query. Using `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()`

Comment: where should i put this ?

Comment: Put `DB::enableQueryLog()` before your query. and put `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` after your query.

Comment: I think there is typo error in where in clause. you are using statut which may status. look at there

Comment: @Sagar He is french guy.

Comment: I don't know, sorry about that.

Comment: hahha !! it's find i found the solution with that ! thanks a lot guys !!!

Comment: You can share the solution, so that someone having same issue can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use closure.

```
$licencies = Licencies::whereIn('structure_id', $structures->pluck('id'))->whereIn(function ($query){
             $query->whereIn('type_licence_id', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4']);
        })
        ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
        ->where('lb_assurance_etat' ,'=' , 'Assurée')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to check your query statement:

Firstly, before the statement:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

secondly, use `dd` to print your sql after the statement:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

finally, copy and paste the sql in you database client, you'll get what you want. And you don't need ask anyone with the similar again.