# Laravel nestedwhere Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

I followed this resources for nested where here: [How to combine WHERE clauses in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949380/how-to-combine-where-clauses-in-eloquent) but get the following error while running the codes. The line where it broke was the curly bracket of the callback function, what's wrong here?

```
$providers = DB::table('users')
->where('verified', '=', 1)
->where('status', '=', 1)
->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where(DB::raw('lower(name)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($search)."%")
    ->orWhere(DB::raw('lower(username)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($search)."%")
})
->where('city', '=', $t)
->take($limit)
->toSql();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `;`after your inner `$query`. I think that part could be this:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where(DB::raw('lower(name)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($search)."%")
    ->orWhere(DB::raw('lower(username)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($search)."%");
})
```

The code needs that semicolon at the end, because it is a line / statement in a function. It does not matter that this function is a callback.

Comment: damn. you are right. it was staring at me all the time.

Comment: No worries, this happens to almost everyone at some point. Glad I could help :)